# how could I make list of lists from neo4j record

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j

I am facing list manipulation from loop iteration. I  am trying to populate a list from Neo4j record

```
myquery="""MATCH (c :Customer {walletId:$item})-[:MR|:SENDS_MONEY]-(d)-[:PAYS]->(m)
               WHERE NOT (c)-[]-(m)
               RETURN c.walletId, m.walletId, m.name, COUNT(m.name) ORDER BY COUNT(m.name) DESC LIMIT 30"""
        result=graphdbsessionwallet.run(myquery,item=item)
        #print(result)


        for record in  result:

              print(list(record))
```

and my current result is

```
['01302268120', '01685676658', 'Shojon Medical Hall', 6]
['01302268216', '01733243988', 'APEXFOOTWEAR LIMITED', 1]
```

and so on 
desired

```
[['01302268120', '01685676658', 'Shojon Medical Hall', 6],['01302268216', '01733243988', 'APEXFOOTWEAR LIMITED', 1]]
```

I want to  put this lists into one list  , kindly help me to solve this

Comment: Could you please add the desired list to question? Because of different nature of items it seem not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query to return the list with the help of `COLLECT` clause:

```
MATCH (c :Customer {walletId:$item})-[:MR|:SENDS_MONEY]-(d)-[:PAYS]->(m)
WHERE NOT (c)-[]-(m)
WITH c, m, COUNT(m.name) as cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC 
RETURN COLLECT([c.walletId, m.walletId, m.name, cnt])
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: This is giving error:Can't use aggregate functions inside of aggregate functions.

Comment: It should be cnt instead of Count inside collect.

Comment: um thanks for answer the query works. but the result is undesirable. after printing result it is showing a neo4j object after iterating over it it is giving list for every iteration value,  i have  [x,y,z],[y,z,x]  now but I want to merge like [[x,y,z],[y,z,x]] as my final output